# $f:X\to Y$ extends to a map $Z\to Y$ iff $f_*[g] = 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, quotient-spaces, universal-property, higher-homotopy-groups

> Let $f \colon(X,x_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ and $g \colon(S^n,s_0)\to (X,x_0)$ be base
>   point preserving maps. 
>   Let $Z$ be the space that arises from $X$ by attaching an $(n+1)$-disk via $g$.

I want to prove that $f_*[g]=0 \in \pi_n(Y,y_0)$ implies that $f$ extends to a map $Z\to Y$.

My attempt: $f_*[g]=0$ implies there is a homotopy $$H \colon S^n\times[0,1]\to Y$$ from $f\circ g$ to the constant map. Therefore $H$ induces a homotopy $$\tilde H \colon S^n\times[0,1]/S^n\times\{1\}\to Y$$ for which we have $\tilde H(\cdot,0) = f\circ g$.

Now, here is where I am kind of stuck. I figured out that by using the universal property of the pushout, I get the following diagram

[image]

If this is correct, I could conclude that by the universal property the dashed arrow is the desired extension of $f$.

**Now my issue is**, that I didnt know about pushouts in the first place and stumbled upon them after I was having difficulties understanding the geometric explanation of the given solution.

The solution followed af first the same direction I was taking but then says:

> On the boundary $S^n\subset D^{n+1}$ (which corresponds to the height
>    $0$ part of $S^n\times[0,1]/(S^{n}\times\{1\})$ the map $H$ is
>    precisely $f\circ g$ (if the identification with $D^{n+1}$ is chosen
>    appropriately). Thus the map $X\sqcup D^{n+1}\to Y$ which is $f$ on
>    the first component and $\tilde H$ on the second, induces a map $Z\to
>  Y$ which extends $f$.

Okay, I already know that $\tilde H(\cdot, 0) = f\circ g$. But (without having the pushout property in mind), how can I conclude everything that follows from there? Is there a geometrical intuition I am missing? Or is the solution implicitely using the universal property of the pushout either?

(I am kind of assuming that's the case since I don't see how else we would induce the extension of $f$ "naturally").

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The intuition behind this is exactly the same as when you have a degree $0$ map on the boundary of a disk, and you can extend this to the whole disk. If you haven't thought through this or done that exercise, try that first. Basically, the time portion of the homotopy is used along the radial lines of the attaching disk. On the boundary of the disk, you use the homotopy at time $t = 0$, and as you move radially inward, you get to $t =1$. At $t = 1$, the map is constant.

Comment: I think you may be thinking too hard about pushouts. The statement of this pushout is just a restatement of the quotient topology when you glue spaces together along a common subspace.

Comment: Just from a topological perspective, why do i need $\tilde H(\cdot, 0) = f\circ g$ in order to induce a map $X\sqcup D^{n+1} \to Y$? My solution and my diagram  is correct?

Comment: That's not what's needed to induce a map. What's needed is that since $H$ itself is constant $S^n \times \{1\}$, by the quotient topology, this descends to a map $\tilde{H}$ from $S^n \times [0,1]/S^n \times \{1\}$, which is itself homeomorphic to $D^{n+1}$. If $H$ were not nullhomotopic, this would not be true, and so would not descend to a map on the disc. By the way we've constructed $\tilde{H}$, it immediately follows that $\tilde{H}(\cdot, 0) = f \circ g$. This is great because that means that it extends $f$ i.e. the two maps agree along the gluing $S^n$.

Comment: More generally, if you have some maps $X_1 \rightarrow Y$ and $X_2 \rightarrow Y$, and you glue $X_1$ and $X_2$ by identifying some points (obtaining $X$), then you can extend your original maps to $X$ exactly when they agree at the points you've identified! (as they must)

Comment: Ah, perfect. The last two comments made it clear. My issue was that i interpreted $f\circ g$ wrong in this scenario. I was always thinking bout its Domain and Codomain. But the key observation here is that $\tilde H$ agrees with $f$ on the image of $g$, i.e. $f\circ g$. Thanks to both of you. Last question: The way i've done it via the diagram was correct?

Comment: Yes it's right! But you don't need the diagram. It essentially restates the universal property of quotient maps, and usually you can assume that. You can write it in one line saying since $H$ descends to the quotient and agrees with $f$ on $S^n$, you have a well-defined map $X \cup_g D^{n+1} \to Y$.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much Osama.